# Replace string in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, pyspark

I am having a dataframe, with numbers in European format, which I imported as a String. Comma as decimal and vice versa -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,col
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
df = spark.createDataFrame([('-1.269,75',)], ['revenue'])
df.show()
+---------+
|  revenue|
+---------+
|-1.269,75|
+---------+
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- revenue: string (nullable = true)
```

**Output desired:**
df.show()

```
+---------+
|  revenue|
+---------+
|-1269.75|
+---------+
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- revenue: float (nullable = true)
```

I am using function `regexp_replace` to first *replace dot with empty space* - then *replace comma with empty dot* and finally cast into floatType.

```
df = df.withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace(col('revenue'), ".", ""))
df = df.withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace(col('revenue'), ",", "."))
df = df.withColumn('revenue', df['revenue'].cast("float"))
```

But, when I attempt replacing below, I get empty string. Why?? I was expecting `-1269,75`.

```
df = df.withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace(col('revenue'), ".", ""))
+-------+
|revenue|
+-------+
|       |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to escape `.` to match it literally, as `.` is a special character that [matches almost any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in regex:

```
df = df.withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace(col('revenue'), "\\.", ""))
```